# VPN application in React Native - [not work react-native-ip-sec-vpn]

Tags: react-native, npm, vpn

I have been trying to create a VPN application in React Native for a few days. But I could only find one. The following package does not work:

npm:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ip-sec-vpn

github:
https://github.com/sijav/react-native-ip-sec-vpn/tree/master/example

Error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepare' of undefined

what is the problem? Is there another way?

Comment: Please help me!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Maybe an issue with the package itself? I don't know. I also need help on this